# Is there any way to make `Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch` work with `ApiKeyAuthentication`?

Tags: asp.net-core, elasticsearch, serilog-sinks-elasticsearch

##### I tried to make [Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch](https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch) work with `ApiKeyAuthentication`, however, it only worked with `BasicAuthentication`.

I tried with two overloads of the `ApiKeyAuthentication` method:

- `ApiKeyAuthentication(ApiKeyAuthenticationCredentials credentials)`
- `ApiKeyAuthentication(string id, string apiKey)`

but the sink doesn't work with `ApiKeyAuthentication`.
[image]

##### However, when I use the `BasicAuthentication(string username, string password)` it works well.

I know that I need to use an apikey with **index create** e **index pattern create** authorization, so I created an apikey with these roles and beyond but still doesn't work.

Also, all the examples I found use BasicAuthentication.

##### Has anyone managed to make this sink work with apikey authentication?

Comment: May I ask if you were able to get a solution @Maicon